# Attribute vector emptying itself

Tags: c++

I have two classes, derived from a common class.
The common class has a pure virtual function called execute(), which is implemented in both derived classes.
In the inherited class I have an attribute which is a vector. In both execute() methods I overwrite this vector with a result. I access both classes from a vector of pointers to their objects.
The problem is when I try to access the result vector form outside the objects. In one case I can get the elements (which are simply pointers), in the other I cannot, the vector is empty.

Code:

```
class E;
class A{
  protected:
    vector<E*> _result;
  public:
    virtual void execute()=0;
    vector<E*> get_result();
};
vector<E*> A::get_result()
{
   return _result;
}
class B : public A
{
  public:
    virtual void execute();
};
B::execute()
{
   //...
   _result = tempVec;
   return;
}
class C : public A
{
  public:
    virtual void execute();
};
C::execute()
{
   //different stuff to B
   _result = tempvec;
   return;
}
main()
{
  B* b = new B();
  C* c = new C();
  b->execute();
  c->execute();
  b->get_result();//returns full vector
  c->get_result(); //returns empty vector!!
}
```

I have no idea what is going on here... I have tried filling _result by hand from a temp vector in the offending class, doing the same with vector::assign(), nothing works. And the other object works perfectly. I must be missing something....
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this the *real* code that produces error, or just an approximation?
This example wouldn't compile - tempvec/tempVec are undeclared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since everything else is the same between classes `B` and `C` I would have to say that the line

```
//different stuff to B
```

is probably important!

Also your `get_result()` method should really be

```
const vector<E*>& get_result() const;
```

to save you making a copy of the vector each time.

Comment: I agree, the problem probably lies somewhere else, the shown code seems perfectly ok to me.

Comment: there is some difference, they process different vectors: tempVec and tempvec.

Comment: OK I've found the bug, it of course had nothing to do with the shown code. I was accessing my objects from a vector of A*, and I had hard coded and index. So it was looking in the wrong object. Typically I spent an hour looking, posted the problem here, and promptly found the problem...
Thanks very much anyway!

Comment: @Max: Yes, I was assuming that that's just a typo. since the real code has been omitted. Of course you never know... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering where that tempVec was coming from but after Troubadour's response I realized that you were omitting code.  There's got to be a problem there as I don't see anything going wrong with the code at this point.

Comment: OK I've found the bug, it of course had nothing to do with the shown code. I was accessing my objects from a vector of A*, and I had hard coded and index. So it was looking in the wrong object. Typically I spent an hour looking, posted the problem here, and promptly found the problem...
Thanks very much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the matter. In class B ::execute method is saving tempVec, (V - is big), in class C it is saving tempvec. well, tempVec - is not empty, tempvec - is empty. Don't see anything wrong.

Comment: OK I've found the bug, it of course had nothing to do with the shown code. I was accessing my objects from a vector of A*, and I had hard coded and index. So it was looking in the wrong object. Typically I spent an hour looking, posted the problem here, and promptly found the problem...
Thanks very much anyway!